# Recommendation for Sharepoint Collaboration site

Tags: collaboration

our environment runs Sharepoint Server 2013 and Office Online Server 2016 for our internal intranet. I'd like to know your thoughts on opening up an external Collaboration site.

I've read mixed opinions with some opting for just adding another web application and others stating that could be a security risk and to have the external site on a separate server.

I apologize as I understand this is opinion based question, but I'd definitely appreciate any feedback from anyone that has worked on anything similar to this.

Comment: how do you wnt the external users to login? Do you have other extranet sites(non-SharePoint) already in your company? Do you have plans for moving to Office 365 (coz external collaboration is built in there)?

Comment: Thanks for replying. We have an external site (non SharePoint) but doesnt have a login function. I was reading many go with forms based authentication. In all honesty I don't see us moving to office 365 anytime soon